# What is Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context?

Tags: php, encryption, authentication

I want to encrypt password in php by use md5 function and I have got an error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in ....(line)

This code I follow up from [this link](https://code-boxx.com/simple-password-encryption-php/) but it was error. I tried to search the similar question on stackoverflow but I doesn't found the same case as me. This is my code. Anyone can help me, please?

The line that found error. `$this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);`

This is my code

```
<?php
    require_once('connect01.php');

    function addUser($name, $password){
        $hash = md5($password);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `user` (`username`, `pass`) VALUES ('$name','$password')";
        $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        return $this->stmt->execute([$name, $hash]);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        addUser($_POST['username'], $_POST['pass']);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: your function isn't wrapped within a class definition, therefore `$this` is unavailable for use. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: **DO NOT USE MD5 FOR PASSWORD HASHING**.  Use `password_hash` and `password_verify`.  Seriously.  Please.  Pleaaaaassseee.

Comment: You need to have placeholders in your query. It won't bind otherwise. `md5` is not an encryption (and passwords shouldn't be encrypted). e.g. ``$sql = "INSERT INTO `user` (`username`, `pass`) VALUES (?, ?)";``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this` is not particularly useful outside of a class. Once you [learn about classes](/questions/20649820#answer-20649999), you can go back to that site you found.

If you want to use `addUser()`, you need a class  where the `$pdo` class property is an instance of the [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) class and the `$statement` class property is an instance of the [PDOStatement](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)

[The previous page](https://code-boxx.com/simple-php-mvc-example/#sec-model) showed you a script named `database.php` containing the `DB` class, a model in the [model-view-controller](/questions/1737868#answer-1737903) design pattern. It fits the requirements stated above.

The most direct way to get this up and running is to add the `DB` class definition to your script and put the function definition of `addUser()` inside of it.

Once you have that set up, and once you learn about [inheritance](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.extends), you may consider keeping the `DB` class in your script but leaving as you found it, without `addUsers()`. You can still use and add to it if you `extends` it:

```php
class User extends DB
{
    function addUser($name, $password)
    {
        $hash = md5($password);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `user` (`username`, `pass`) VALUES ('$name','$password')";
        $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        return $this->stmt->execute([$name, $hash]);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that if you choose this approach, you will need to change `DB::$pdo` and `DB::$stmt` from `private` to `protected`:

```php
class DB
{
    protected $pdo = null;
    protected $stmt = null;
/* keep the rest of the class the same */
```

This is because `private` class properties are not usable ("visible") by a class that extends the first class, but `protected` class properties are. This is part of a concept called [visibility](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).